# Picasso loads image thumbnail only in the last item in a recyclerView

Tags: android

Picasso loads the thumbnail only on the last item in my recyclerview. I used the firebase recyclerAdapter; [this is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLG1s.png)

As shown in my code, I set the username text to the image url to check what was really going on and to my surprise the image url was retrieved correctly for each itemView.

[This is the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hggOh.png)

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);
   mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
   mdatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
   mdatabase.keepSynced(true);

   CurrentUser_id=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    friendsDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends").child(CurrentUser_id);
    friendsDatabase.keepSynced(true);



    recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewFriends);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);




    options= new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model_Users>().setQuery(friendsDatabase,Model_Users.class).build();
    adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model_Users, Users_ViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Users_ViewHolder users_viewHolder, int i, @NonNull Model_Users users) {

            final String userid=getRef(i).getKey();


            mdatabase.child(userid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String username=dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();
                    String status=dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
                    String image=dataSnapshot.child("profileImage").getValue().toString();


                    users_viewHolder.setUsername(image);
                    users_viewHolder.setStatus(status);
                    users_viewHolder.setimage(image);
```

//

```
                    users_viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(),ProfileActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("Data",userid);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });



                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });



        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Users_ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view =LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.friendslist,parent,false);
            return new Users_ViewHolder(view);
        }
    };
```

Comment: where is the picasso code

Answer (score 0):

To Show Image using Picasso Use this code :

```
//here image will be the link of your image
Picasso.get().load(image).into(users_viewHolder.imageView);
```

Add this to build.gradle :

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Comment: Picasso.get().load(image).into(users_viewHolder.imageView); crashes my app

Comment: The problem occurs even with glide

Comment: Share your logcat . One more thing . image must be a link.

Comment: Yes, the image is a firebase link, Please take a look at the screenshot below
     https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLG1s.png

Comment: Can you share the log-cat ?

Comment: Sorry to ask but i am new here, should i add it to the question

Comment: Sure. You can do it.

Comment: i have added the log-cat

Comment: This is not you crash log . run the app and when app crashes . Get the fatal main error and give me the ss . Also change logcat info to debug.

Comment: please check the log now

Comment: Where is fatal main log? this is not how to deal with it . when your app crashes it will return fatal main error in logcat with red text color.

Comment: the app does not crash, it just does not load the images as it is suppose to

Comment: or do you mean when i use the latest version of picasso?

Comment: i just added the picasso dependency and the app crashed without any error in the log-cat, i am confused

Comment: try again . now change it debud to verbose and after app crash press Ctrl+f and type fatal main.